# How can I make sure that the state gets update immediately after i refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The state is not getting updated when i refresh the page, although it does get updated sometimes when I restart the development server. Can someone help me debug?

````
function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [q, setQ] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {

    console.log('triggered')
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/getCollege').then(
      response =>
        response.json())
      .then(json => {
        setData(json)
        console.log(data.length)
      });





  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <div>filter goes here</div>
      <div>datatable goes here</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App; ```
````

Comment: How are you refreshing the page?

Comment: did you check the network tab in debug console in your browser? whether network request is fired or not?

Answer (score 0):

Notice in the `useEffect`, if the second parameter is a `[]`, this means the effect function will only run **ONCE** after the component render. To tackle, you should take out the [].

If you want the effect re-run based on some variables, you can then put it in that dependency array(eg. [someState, someProps, ...])

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('triggered')
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/getCollege').then(
      response =>
        response.json())
      .then(json => {
        setData(json)
        console.log(data.length)
      });
  })
```